# Проверка графа на ацикличность обходом в глубину без рекурсии

Tags: c#, алгоритм, рекурсия, графы, стек

Есть хороший и понятный алгоритм "серый-черный" - проверка графа на ацикличность. Проблема в том, что обход в глубину этого алгоритма реализуется **рекурсивно**. В C# системный стек по умолчанию не выдержит и 10^5 вершин графа при обходе DFS таким методом. Увеличить размер стека по некоторым причинам не имею возможности.

Вопрос в следующем: возможно ли реализовать алгоритм нахождения цикла в графе через стековый DFS, а не рекурсивный?

Comment: Возможно. Используйте стек для хранения вершин.

Comment: Любой рекурсивный алгоритм можно реализовать нерекурсивно, создавая свой стек.

Comment: Действительно, через стек возможно воспроизведение алгоритма DFS, однако стекового варианта недостаточно для работы алгоритма нахождения цикла. Вопрос и заключался в том, есть ли такая разновидность стекового DFS, чтобы была возможна реализация "покраски" вершин в серый при входе в вершину, и черный при выходе из нее.

Comment: `однако стекового варианта недостаточно для работы алгоритма нахождения цикла` - на чём основано это утверждение? Ничего не мешает построить нерекурсивный вариант с явным стеком, надо только не забывать, что в стеке сохранять нужно не только номер вершины, но и текущее состояние (например - сколько соседей обошли).

Comment: Речь конечна шла о том, что стандартного варианта (без модификации) не хватает. Подтолкнули на мысль сохранения кол-ва соседей. Подумаю насчет реализацией. Если есть конкретная задумка -  буду рад выслушать.